# How to access feathers services from beforeRouteEnter in Vue Components?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, feathersjs

I want to determine if a Vue Component should be loaded, based on the Route that was requested.

For instance if a user goes to `http://todo.example.com/task/123`, I would like to check if `123` is a valid task_id before loading the Component. If the id is not valid, I would simply redirect the user, and not have to load the Component.

I know that `vue-feathers` registers a `$feathers` property on Vue Components to be able to access your Feathers Services. But the problem is that in the `beforeRouteEnter` method provided by `vue-router`, the component has not been loaded yet, and therefor I can not access my Services through `this.$feathers`.

I also know that I would be able to access Component Instance by passing a callback in to the `next` function, but that would also defeat the purpose of trying to not load the Component if the task_id is not valid.

I am hoping there is a more global way to access Feathers Services.

Answer (score 0):

Create an intermediate component, route to it, and then do a `$router.replace` based on your needs.

You can then use `$feathers` as a param in your replaced route.